# Header moves slightly when changing to fixed positioning

Tags: html, css

I have a page header which scrolls with the user whenever they pass it in the scroll. I do this using `position: absolute` and switching it to `position: fixed` once they reach it. The problem I'm having is that when the element turns to `position: fixed` it jumps slightly, making the transition really noticeable. How do I prevent this?

[image]

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v1zf1g2L/4/

In the fiddle I use a number of transforms, this is done so the header can escape a containing element on the site it lives on (Something I cannot change). **I've tried making the attach class use the same transform styles as the header class and just changing the position, but this causes a conflict with another element of mine meaning this approach does not work for my use.**

```
.header {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: blue;
}

.attach {
  position: fixed;
  -webkit-transform: none;
  transform: none;
  -moz-transform: none;
  -ms-transform: none;
  -o-transform: none;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: 4 answers now all read this issue as the menu not having `top:0;` in the absolute state. Can you reword the problem or better highlight the issue? Obviously we're having a hard time understanding. You said, "the content within the header shifting slightly when the bar moves to fixed positioning." I've looked at your fiddle a few times now and don't see anything in the header shifting when the menu moves from absolute to fixed. Does your example clearly illustrate that shifting?

Comment: Here's a gif of the problem:  http://i.imgur.com/v9h9UQC.gif

Comment: I'm not seeing it. This is what it looks like to me. The only thing I see shifting is the top value. And mayyyybe a 1px to the left/right difference since you're using `left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);` in the absolute state and `left: 0;` in the fixed state. http://i.imgur.com/Gwj1mkn.gif

Comment: That slight left/right shift is what I'm looking to avoid. I also updated the fiddle to mimmick the situation this element is placed within normally.

Comment: Also wanted to note I've tried switching the styles on the attach class to be the same as the header class except with `position: fixed;` but it causes a conflict with another element of mine :(

Comment: Why don't you use `left: 0;` `.header`, remove the `transform` lines, and remove the `left: 0;` from `.attach`? https://jsfiddle.net/v1zf1g2L/6/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need ?

```js
   function checkScroll() {
     if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
       $("#header").addClass("attach").css("top", "0");
     } else {
       $("#header").removeClass("attach").css("top", "0");
     }
   }

   $(window).scroll(function() {
     checkScroll();
   })
```

```css
.header {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: blue;
    transition:all .4s linear;
    top:0;
}

.attach {
  position: fixed;
  -webkit-transform: none;
  transform: none;
  -moz-transform: none;
  -ms-transform: none;
  -o-transform: none;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: red;
  transition:all .4s linear;
}
.content  { padding-top:110px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header" class="header">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/00I8dSr.png" style="width: 200px" />
</div>

<div class="content">
  <p>
    blah 1
  </p>
  <p>
    blah
  </p>
  <p>
    blah
  </p>
  <p>
    blah
  </p>
  <p>
    blah
  </p>
  <p>
    blah
  </p>
  <p>
    blah
  </p>
  <p>
    blah
  </p>
  <p>
    blah
  </p>
  <p>
    blah
  </p>
  <p>
    blah
  </p>
  <p>
    blah
  </p>
  <p>
    blah
  </p>
  <p>
    blah
  </p>
  <p>
    blah
  </p>
  <p>
    blah
  </p>
  <p>
    blah
  </p>
  <p>
    blah
  </p>
  <p>
    blah
  </p>
  <p>
    blah
  </p>
  <p>
    blah
  </p>
  <p>
    blah
  </p>
  <p>
    blah
  </p>
  <p>
    blah
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: No it's not, because the menu scrolls with the user when they reach it in the scroll, I'm not looking for it to start at the top. I am trying to avoid the content shifting within the header when it switches from absolute to fixed.

Comment: @Shahil James is saying the problem is the 1px horizontal shift between `.header` which uses `left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);` and `.attach` chich uses `left: 0;`

Comment: @MichaelCoker I am confused with this.

Answer (score 0):

I just tweaked it a little bit! You have to make sure that both are right at the top and left!

Here you have:
https://jsfiddle.net/w487771f/

```
function checkScroll() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
    $("#header").removeClass("header");
    $("#header").addClass("attach");
  } else {
    $("#header").removeClass("attach");
    $("#header").addClass("header");
  }
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
  checkScroll();
})


.header {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: none;
  transform: none;
  -moz-transform: none;
  -ms-transform: none;
  -o-transform: none;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 999;
}

.attach {
  position: fixed;
  -webkit-transform: none;
  transform: none;
  -moz-transform: none;
  -ms-transform: none;
  -o-transform: none;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi you can use like these

JS

```
 $("#header").addClass("attach");
$("#header").removeClass("attach");
```